# Bayesian model selection, functional form of variance

Tags: regression, bayesian, variance, model-selection

I'm working on a linear regression model of the form,
$$y = X\beta + \epsilon(X) $$ 
where each 
$$\epsilon_i \sim N(0, \sigma^2_i)$$

My variance term is depends on a subset of the regressors $X$.  The forms I am considering would be something like:

$$\sigma^2_i = (\mathbf x_i'\alpha)^2,\;\;\;\sigma^2_i = \exp(\mathbf x_i'\alpha), \;\;\;\sigma^2_i = \sigma^2(\mathbf x_i'\beta)^2$$

For my application the goal is to predict new values of the dependent variable $y$ (not its best estimate) along with the proper uncertainty.  So the parts of the model regarding the predicted values and the predictive uncertainty are equally important.

What I'm wondering about is how to approach the model selection phase.  I will need to assess both how accurate the predicted $y$ values are, as well as if my predicted spread matches the actual predicted spread.

How suitable are quantities like BIC for this?  I know BIC measures the trade off between fit and model complexity, but I think having extra parameters to model the variance will add model complexity while not change the fit per se, just the quality of the variance of the predictions.  Would BIC take this into account?  **What would be the best approach for model selection in this situation?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let us consider $\sigma_{i}^{2} = (x_{i}^{T}\alpha)^{2}$ For the $i^{th}$ entry in the vector, can be reformulated as

$ y_{i} =x_{i}^{T}\beta + x_{i}^{T}u$ where $u \sim N(0,\alpha^{2})$.

In matrix form this becomes

$ y = X\beta + Xu$ where $u \sim N(0,\alpha^{2} I)$

This is a standard mixed linear model so all diagnostics for that method will work here. Not surprisingly, all of these models will involve some variant of the EM algorithm